# Rendering same React Component with different properties at different div id

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to render single react component with different properties at different div id

```
index.html:
<div class="container" id="root1"></div>
<div class="container" id="root2"></div>
```

There are two hyperlinks and onClick will catch the id of the hyperlink, I have bound root1 and root2 to both the hyperlinks and calls the function(prop, containerID)

```
file.js:
function(prop, containerID){
   ReactDOM.render(<component prop={prop}/>, document.getElemntById(containerID));
}
```

after this statements i can see only 'prop2' at both the divisions 'root1' and 'root2' and if i change the order of ReactDOM.render by 'root2' and then 'root1', then only 'prop1' is visible at both 'root1' and 'root2'.

But I need 'prop1' at 'root1' and 'prop2' at 'root2'.

Is there anything I need to add more to the above code or any other alternative way to implement this view?

Comment: I do the same thing with a simple Counter component and it works for me. Can you please post the code of the component that you are using?

Comment: On top of posting more of the code, what versions of react and react-dom are you using?

Comment: @palsrealm component returns <p>{this.props.prop}</p>

Comment: @ZekeDroid 
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/react/0.14.0-rc1/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/react/0.14.0-rc1/react-dom.js"></script>

Comment: Could you try upgrading to a stable v15? Your code looks correct as is

Comment: @ZekeDroid
i tried with new fb.me/react-15.0.0.js and same for react-dom but no luck!

Comment: I tried with the version you are using and it worked for me. https://codepen.io/palsrealm/pen/oGqrRZ . Can you post more of your code using a codepen?

Comment: @palsrealm thanks for the update and i am really sorry for posting the question in a different way. I have updated my question and this is the generic form because it can contain multiple div and i have written generic function which handles for every div.

Comment: You would need to provide more code for us to help you with the issue. And  you should also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  in your free time! :)

Comment: @palsrealm i totally understand that and i appreciate for the link. As i am new i am not good with all the terms. And i cant provide more code because its part of private organization. So, i try to get the solution by presenting the view than presenting the code.

Comment: @palsrealm i tried with supplying id for 'every' level of component and then it worked. I have more than 15 levels of nested component levels and with no id's before. 

So maybe there is no id to distinguish, it is treating the whole DOM tree same for both divisions and trying to reflect the changes for both the div. But the case which you gave me through codepen works without the concept of id. So, still i am not sure why that happened.